# What does "var dialogs = {};" mean in jQuery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry to bother you all here but I am still trying to understand more about some javascript code that I am working on. I just recently asked a question about dialogs[id] = $(); Now I look further up the code and see something else I am not familiar with.

Can someone explain what the purpose of "var dialogs = {}" is in this context. Thanks,

```
 $(function () {
// Cache for dialogs
var dialogs = {};

var getValidationSummaryErrors = function ($form) {
    // We verify if we created it beforehand
    var errorSummary = $form.data('validation-summary-errors');
    if (!errorSummary) {
        errorSummary = $('<div class="validation-summary-errors"><span>Please correct the errors and try again.</span><ul></ul></div>')
            .insertBefore($form);

        // Remember that we created it
        $form.data('validation-summary-errors', errorSummary);
    }

    return errorSummary;
};

var formSubmitHandler = function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
    if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray())
            .done(function (json) {
                json = json || {};

                // In case of success, we redirect to the provided URL or the same page.
                if (json.success) {
                    location = json.redirect || location.href;
                } else if (json.errors) {
                    var errorSummary = getValidationSummaryErrors($form);

                    var items = $.map(json.errors, function (error) {
                        return '<li>' + error + '</li>';
                    }).join('');

                    var ul = errorSummary
                        .find('ul')
                        .empty()
                        .append(items);
                }
            });
    }

    // Prevent the normal behavior since we opened the dialog
    e.preventDefault();
};

var loadAndShowDialog = function (id, link, url) {
    var separator = url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?';

    // Save an empty jQuery in our cache for now.
    dialogs[id] = $();

    // Load the dialog with the content=1 QueryString in order to get a PartialView
    $.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
        .done(function (content) {
            dialogs[id] = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>')
                .hide() // Hide the dialog for now so we prevent flicker
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .filter('div') // Filter for the div tag only, script tags could surface
                .dialog({ // Create the jQuery UI dialog
                    title: link.data('dialog-title'),
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    width: link.data('dialog-width') || 300
                })
                .find('form') // Attach logic on forms
                    .submit(formSubmitHandler)
                .end();
        });
};

// List of link ids to have an ajax dialog
var links = ['logonLink', 'registerLink'];

$.each(links, function (i, id) {
    $('#' + id).click(function (e) {
        var link = $(this),
            url = link.attr('href');

        if (!dialogs[id]) {
            loadAndShowDialog(id, link, url);
        } else {
            dialogs[id].dialog('open');
        }

        // Prevent the normal behavior since we use a dialog
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

});

Note that this is the complete javascript. There's nothing more that's not shown here.

**Also:** Is it needed?

Comment: Added the [tag:javascript] tag because this is not a jQuery-specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It instantiates a new [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) without any own properties or methods. Basically the same as saying

```
var dialogs = new Object();
```

The `{}` notation is called an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals).

---

It is **needed** in this code. The variable `dialogs` is used to keep track of existing (already created) dialogs, so they don't have to be created each time they are opened. Several lines reference this variable if you take a closer look. `dialogs` is declared at the top (`var dialogs = {}`) so every other function at the same level can use it (read up on [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)).

I have marked the places in your code when the `dialogs` object is used. Don't let the `dialogs[id]` notation fool you - `dialogs` is not an array (Javascript has no associative arrays), but an object here, so it is equivalent to `dialogs.id`.

```
$(function () { //this is used not to pollute the global scope

var dialogs = {}; //HERE - dialogs is declared in this local scope

...

var loadAndShowDialog = function (id, link, url) {
    var separator = url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?';

    dialogs[id] = $(); //HERE - dialogs.id will be an empty jQuery object

    $.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
        .done(function (content) {
            //HERE - dialogs.id becomes a (jQuery-wrapped) div 
            //with the appropriate content
            dialogs[id] = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>')
               ...
        });
};

...
$.each(links, function (i, id) {
    $('#' + id).click(function (e) {
        ...  
        if (!dialogs[id]) { //HERE - if a dialog with this id does not exist
            loadAndShowDialog(id, link, url); //load a new one
        } else { //otherwise
            dialogs[id].dialog('open'); //HERE - open the existing dialog
        }
        ...
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Without any *own* properties or methods.

Comment: Just adding: you're using the `dialogs` object in your `loadAndShowDialog` function (from your previous question). by calling `dialogs[id]`, you're accessing a dynamic property of the object. It's like trying to set `dialogs.foo = "bar"`, but the `foo` part is dynamic, unknown, and can be changed.

Answer (score 5):

`{}` is the shortcut for creating a new object (like `[]` is for arrays), so `var dialogs = {}` just creates an empty object without any properties.

Comment: Do I really need this in the script? I cannot see where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

It declares an empty Javascript object, which can then have properties dynamically added to it for storage.

EDIT: Note that there are two ways of accessing properties on an object in Javascript. The first is using "dot notation", i.e. `object.property`.

The second is using brackets, e.g. `object['property']`. They are more or less the same thing.

Also, because Javascript is a dynamic language, if you set a property that doesn't exist on the object, it creates it for you, then sets it.

Given this, you should be able to spot where this `dialogs` object is used in your code. Hint: It uses the latter notation. :-)

Comment: Very quick answer :-) But is it even used here in the script? Note that I was previously asking also if dialogs[id] = $(); was needed. One person suggested maybe not.

Comment: @SamanthaJ I have updated my answer. Can you spot the places where it is used now?